# Problemas ao carregar um DataTable no Load da Página com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-datatables, javascript-eventos

Sou iniciante com JavaScript e estou tendo um problema quando o DataTable da minha Index é carregado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu abrir uma seção , na minha Index, e colocar o código JS dentro dela, tudo funciona perfeitamente.

```js
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Gerenciar Situações de Pessoa";
}

<div class="panel animsition">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">situacoes-gerenciamento/listar-todos</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="page-header-actions">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm"
                 role="group">
                <a id="btnNovo" asp-action="Create" data-modal="" class="btn btn-outline btn-default new" data-toggle="tooltip"
                   data-original-title="Cadastrar Novo" data-container="body">
                    <span title="Cadastrar Novo" class="icon wb-plus"></span> Cadastrar Novo
                </a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Configurações" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-settings" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Exportar" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Importar" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Imprimir" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Pesquisa Avançada" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs">Pesquisa Avançada</span>
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="page-content">

        <table id="pessoaSituacaoTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered center-header " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Id
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Descrição
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Tipo de Pessoa
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Ações
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalPessoaSituacao" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 45%; height: 500px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="contentModal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {

        $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search...').hide();
        var table = $("#pessoaSituacaoTable").DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            //"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("getPessoaSituacao", "PessoaSituacao")',
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [3] },
            { className: "align-right", "targets": [0] }
        ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "descricao", "name": "Descricao", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "pessoaTipoDescricao", "name": "PessoaTipo", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": null, "name": "Action", "defaultContent": '<a title="Editar" asp-action="Edit" data-modal="" data-id="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default edit-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-edit"></span></a> |' +
                    '<a title="Detalhes" asp-action="Details" data-modal="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default footable-row-detail-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-search"></span></a> |' +
                    '<a title="Excluir" asp-action="Delete" data-modal="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default remove-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-trash"></span></a> |' +
                    '<a title="Histórico" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default clockpicker" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pessoaHistory" data-original-title="Histórico"><span class="icon-2x wb-time"></span></a>', "autoWidth": true
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ".",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Digite algo...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sNext": "Próximo",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                    "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                    "sLast": "Último"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                }
            }

        });

        $('.search-input').on('keyup change', function () {
            var index = $(this).attr('data-column'),
                val = $(this).val();
            table.columns(index).search(val.trim()).draw();
        });


        });

   
}
```

PROBLEMA: Se eu transferir o código para um script JS e referenciá-lo na minha Index, não funciona e fica exibindo a mensagem de erro que eu citei acima. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```js
//Meu Arquivo PessoaSituacao.js

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    // busca os elementos do atributo data-modal e o vincula ao evento click
    $('a[data-modal]').on('click', function (e) {
      // Abre a janela modal com o formulário solicitado 
        openmodal(this.href);
        return false;
    });
    $('#modalPessoaSituacao').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#contentModal').html('');
    });

    $(function () {

        $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search...').hide();
        var table = $("#pessoaSituacaoTable").DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            //"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("getPessoaSituacao", "PessoaSituacao")',
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                { className: "align-center", "targets": [3] },
                { className: "align-right", "targets": [0] }
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "descricao", "name": "Descricao", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "pessoaTipoDescricao", "name": "PessoaTipo", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": null, "name": "Action", "defaultContent": '<a title="Editar" asp-action="Edit" data-modal="" data-id="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default edit-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-edit"></span></a> |' +
                    '<a title="Detalhes" asp-action="Details" data-modal="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default footable-row-detail-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-search"></span></a> |' +
                    '<a title="Excluir" asp-action="Delete" data-modal="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default remove-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-trash"></span></a> |' +
                    '<a title="Histórico" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default clockpicker" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pessoaHistory" data-original-title="Histórico"><span class="icon-2x wb-time"></span></a>', "autoWidth": true
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ".",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Digite algo...",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sNext": "Próximo",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                    "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                    "sLast": "Último"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                }
            }

        });

        $('.search-input').on('keyup change', function () {
            var index = $(this).attr('data-column'),
                val = $(this).val();
            table.columns(index).search(val.trim()).draw();
        });


    });
    
});


function openmodal(url) {
    // Faz uma requisição Get e carrega o formulário na janela modal
    $('#contentModal').load(url, function () {
        $('#modalPessoaSituacao').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
         //Enviar o foco para campo Descrição
         $('#modalPessoaSituacao').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
             $("#txtDescricao").focus();
         });   
       // Vincula o evento submit
        bindForm(this);
    });
}
function bindForm(dialog) {
     // Vincula o formulário na janela modalcom o evento submit
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
             // Realiza uma querisição ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    // Se a requisição for satisfatória, a página atual é recarregada
                    if (result.success) {
                        window.location = window.location;
                        window.location.reload(); //Ajuda na exclusao, atualizando o grid

                    } else {
                        $('#contentModal').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Tenta tirar sua função de dentro do $(document).ready() e coloca ele como uma função independente.

Comment: Olá Maycon! Eu tirei tirar de dentro do bloco que vc sugeriu, mas continua o mesmo erro... Não manjo muito bem de JavaScript... Acho estranho esta função sem um nome... Dá impressão que ela executa sem ser chamada.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

e

```
$(function(){}); //modo abrevidado do ready
```

são a mesma coisa, sendo assim não pode chamar um dentro do outro.
O melhor é utilizar o que melhor lhe agrada.

```
$(function(){
  //seus códigos jquery
});
function funcoesJS(){
  //seu código
}
```

Referência:
- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp
- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

======== como ficaria seu código =========

```
//Meu Arquivo PessoaSituacao.js

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    // busca os elementos do atributo data-modal e o vincula ao evento click
    $('a[data-modal]').on('click', function (e) {
      // Abre a janela modal com o formulário solicitado 
        openmodal(this.href);
        return false;
    });
    $('#modalPessoaSituacao').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#contentModal').html('');
    });

    $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search...').hide();
    var table = $("#pessoaSituacaoTable").DataTable({
        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
        //"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        "ajax": {
            "url": '@Url.Action("getPessoaSituacao", "PessoaSituacao")',
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [3] },
            { className: "align-right", "targets": [0] }
        ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "descricao", "name": "Descricao", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "pessoaTipoDescricao", "name": "PessoaTipo", "autoWidth": true },
            {
                "data": null, "name": "Action", "defaultContent": '<a title="Editar" asp-action="Edit" data-modal="" data-id="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default edit-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-edit"></span></a> |' +
                '<a title="Detalhes" asp-action="Details" data-modal="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default footable-row-detail-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-search"></span></a> |' +
                '<a title="Excluir" asp-action="Delete" data-modal="" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default remove-row"><span class="icon-2x wb-trash"></span></a> |' +
                '<a title="Histórico" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default clockpicker" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pessoaHistory" data-original-title="Histórico"><span class="icon-2x wb-time"></span></a>', "autoWidth": true
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "searchPlaceholder": "Digite algo...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }
        }

    });

    $('.search-input').on('keyup change', function () {
        var index = $(this).attr('data-column'),
            val = $(this).val();
        table.columns(index).search(val.trim()).draw();
    });

});


function openmodal(url) {
    // Faz uma requisição Get e carrega o formulário na janela modal
    $('#contentModal').load(url, function () {
        $('#modalPessoaSituacao').modal({
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
         //Enviar o foco para campo Descrição
         $('#modalPessoaSituacao').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
             $("#txtDescricao").focus();
         });   
       // Vincula o evento submit
        bindForm(this);
    });
}
function bindForm(dialog) {
     // Vincula o formulário na janela modalcom o evento submit
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
             // Realiza uma querisição ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    // Se a requisição for satisfatória, a página atual é recarregada
                    if (result.success) {
                        window.location = window.location;
                        window.location.reload(); //Ajuda na exclusao, atualizando o grid

                    } else {
                        $('#contentModal').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Entendi Wilson... Já tentei usar como função independente, mas não funcionou... OU estou colocando o bloco no lugar errado ou tem algum coisa errada conflitando...

Comment: O cabeçalho do meu datatable é carregado primeiro, depois as linhas são criadas usando JS... Eu criei uma funcao function myDataTable(){....} e estou tentando chamá-la em todos os possíveis locais após o grid estar carregado... só que não está funcionando tb... :(

Comment: arrumei seu código para melhor entendimento do que eu queria informar, quanto ao cabeçalho, você já verificou no código fonte gerado pelo navegador a sequência dos arquivos importados, jquery,bootstrap,jquery ui, etc...se estão na ordem certa, confirmou se o caminho de referência dos arquivos estão corretos? Qual navegador vc utiliza o Chrome ou Firefox?

Comment: hummmm.. Uso o Google Chrome. Essa sequência eu não verifiquei não. Fiz conforme sua sugestão e o Datatable começou a querei funcionar (Até apareceu o "Processing..."), mas aí apareceu a janelinha de erro (conforme citei no post) e o as linhas não foram carregadas... Só o cabeçalho carregou.

Comment: O Arquivo está referenciado certinho:  <script src="~/js/cadastros/pessoaSituacao/pessoaSituacao.js"></script>... Os demais arquivos tb estão referenciados corretamente, pois antes, estava usando o datatable, mas como tive que refatorá-lo para otimizar nas pesquisas, começaram os problemas... Incrível que se o script estiver na mesma Index funciona.... se ele se misturar com os outros do arquivo dá problema...

Comment: Consegui resolver! Já que o erro era relacionado ao Ajax, verifiquei que o caminho estava configurado com o Razor ("url": '@Url.Action("getPessoaSituacao", "PessoaSituacao")') e quando eu copiava o bloco para um Script JS Razor não funciona rsrssr Bastou eu mudar a url para ("url": '/situacoes-gerenciamento/getPessoaSituacao') e funcionou 100%. Obrigado :)

Comment: Perfeito, o caminho dos arquivos se forem editados automáticamente as vezes causam problemas.